# Sub-menu :before transition

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a submenu with a border-left looking bar that transitions in height from 0 to 100% upon hover of the main nav element. For some reason the transition is not working. Any help?

http://codepen.io/matthewmorrisux/pen/addLZE?editors=110

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">About</a><ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Process</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>


.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0px;
  background: black;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `display` property to toggle the visibility between `none` and `block`, this does not work well with transitions.

Instead, try hiding the menu and its content by setting the height to 0:

```
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then your `.sub-menu` also needs a height:

```
.menu__item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/addLPR?editors=110

Comment: Thanks! One more thing... how could I make it so an image (http://placehold.it/50x100) transitions out the left side of the sub-menu? As you can see, sub-menu items are transitioning out to the right, now I want an image to transition out to the left.  [http://codepen.io/matthewmorrisux/pen/dGGZVY?editors=110]